# possible to install and use multiple wamp stacks

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp, wampserver

Is it possible to install and run multiple wamp stacks on the same machine, like wampserver2 and xammp and a separate php and apache installation that I installed myself? Should I expect any conflicts? and is there a way to avoid conflicts?

Comment: Check out this post from derick : http://derickrethans.nl/multiple-php-version-setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem I see is to make sure each server listens on a different port.
This can be achieved inside the Apache conf file.  It is well documented and easy to locate the specific entry for **port**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use it on different drives, C/wamp and D/wamp, I did this, because I always had problems few seconds I installed wamp2.2e with apache 2.4.2 and php 5.4.3, and second with apacke 2.2.2 and 5.3.13. (this second one I needed for PTC (paid to click) scripts testing only, and as soon as I had any file configured before manually, and then add new version of apache or php into wamserver pack to use with a simple wamp "switch command", the server didn't start again, or was keeping on orange for 5 mins before it started, or switching to orange, red, ... and then green after 10 switches, or sometimes even stayd on orange. So I simply installed on 2 locations.

It would also be cool if you'd be able to choose the type of installation on beginning, so you could also pick what to install, because you can reuse /apps and /alias from previous installation, and also mysql as well. Well, you can also install just apache and php in different folder (or better drive) if you want...

p.s.: Must set one or another apache to listen to port 8080. I prefered running apache (wamp) and IIS 7 (7.5 and now testing 8), so I had this on 8080, but I've choosen to rather run wamps separately, and when I don't need one or another version, I then turn it off and run IIS, which is mainly on 8080, but if I shut down localhost:80, there's like 5 secs to change the IIS to 80 and start it...

Another options are virtual machies, but I think that's too complicated then if you need to switch between too many versions of apache/php(/mysql), to run each on own, and don't want to have installed on same "wamp server" (one wamp dir) and switch in wampmanager..

Answer (score -1):

It's possible. The easiest, most foolproof way to avoid any kinds of conflicts, especially if you're running different versions of everything, will be to setup a separate virtual machine (see [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/)) for each install.