# Can I have 2 concurrent WAMP Server installations?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

For starters, ***if*** this is possible, I do realize that I would *not* want to try *running* them simultaneously.

**GOAL:**
Migrate my dev env from 64-bit WAMP Server to a 32-bit WAMP Server.

I have finally reached my breaking point ... I *need* to be able to access MS SQL Server from my development environment.
I'd prefer to keep my current stack operable in case I hit any roadblocks and need to get back to actual work before continuing.

**INTENTION:**
My thought is to just do a fresh WAMPSERVER install *along side* of my current installation.  (current install = C:/wamp, new would be something like C:/wamp32)
This way I could thoroughly test everything without the threat of being dead in the water.

**QUESTION:**
Currently, I have WAMPSERVER 2.2 64-bit.
Can I also install WAMPSERVER 2.4 32-bit without glitching the whole thing out?

BTW, my OS is Win7 Pro 64

Comment: There are a couple of answers on this question that may give you a better idea of the potential issues and how to avoid them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088294/possible-to-install-and-use-multiple-wamp-stacks I would say it is possible to install them both but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Just coming back to say YES, you can have concurrent installations.
Everything's working fine.